# How to access a class object and its attributes from user input?

Tags: python, class, object

I just started programming and I decided to use Python for my first attempts at coding, and I am now practicing with classes and objects. 
I apologize if the question I am about to ask has been asked before, but I can't seem to find answers anywhere, so here it goes.

I have a file that contains a class. Below the full code I have written :

```
#class file
#class prodotti  refers to "register" with products in stock and their prices

class Prodotti(): #class Prodotti() contains products from register and their relative specs 
def __init__(self, nome="", #name of product
                   prezzo=0, #product price
                   quantità=0,): #stock quantity of product
    self.nome=nome
    self.prezzo=prezzo
    self.quantità=quantità

def newproduct(self): #method appends new product and its specs to the end of this file
      name=input("Inserire nuovo prodotto: ")
      f=open("cassa3.py", "a")
      f.write(name + "=Prodotti(nome='" + name + "', ")
      price=input("Inserire prezzo prodotto: ")
      f.write("prezzo=" + price + ", quantità=0)\n")
      f.close()

def tellprice(self): #method should return price of object
    inp=input("Di quale prodotto vuoi conoscere il prezzo? ") #asks user which product they want to know the price of
    if inp=Prodotti():
       print(inp.prezzo)

#class objects
#user can insert new products that are saved below
tortino=Prodotti(nome="Tortino al cioccolato", prezzo=3.4, quantità=0)
muffincioccolato =Prodotti(nome="Muffin al cioccolato", prezzo=1.8, quantità=0)
cupcake=Prodotti(nome='cupcake', prezzo=2, quantità=0)
```

In another file, saved in the same directory, I have the main program:

```
from cassa3 import Prodotti #file cassa3.py in same directory as this file



if __name__=="__main__":
P=Prodotti()
P.tellprice()
```

As you may tell from the code above, what I want method tellprice() to do is to ask the user what product they want to know the price of.
However, I just don't know how to make the user input correspond to a class object, so that I can access its attributes.
Can someone explain how i could manage to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Before you will be able to solve this issue, you will need to fix the design problem you have.

Your comment says `# class Prodotti() contains products from register and their relative specs` but it is not quite true. This class contains a single product with its name, price and quantity.

You will need to define another class (perhaps `Register`) that will actually store a list (or dictionary if product names are unique for efficient lookup, or whatever) of products (instances of `Prodotti`).

The `tellprice` method currently makes no sense. It simply creates a new instance of `Prodotti` and the `if` condition will **never** be `True`.

Also, it is highly suggested to use English names in code.

Consider the below example as a general guide:

```
class Product:
    def __init__(self, name, price,  quantity):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.quantity = quantity

    # (... some other methods ... )

class Register:
    def __init__(self, products):
        # this will store the products in a dictionary with products names as keys
        # and Product instances as values for an efficient look up by tell_price
        self.products = {product.name: product for product in products}

    def tell_price(self):
        name = input('Which product would you like to know the price of?')
        # this will raise KeyError if user inputs a non-existing product name
        # and should be caught, or use .get(...) instead
        return self.products[name].price


apple = Product('apple', 1, 10)
banana = Product('banana', 2, 2)

register = Register([apple, banana])

print(register.tell_price())

# Which product would you like to know the price of?
>> apple
# 1
```

Comment: The reason I didn't want to use a dictionary is, there will be multiple parameters that i want to access further on (not only price, but also quantity, and so on). Therefore, I'd have to create multiple dictionaries to make sure I cover it all.   What I wanted to know is if there's any way to simply create new objects of a class using user input, something I couldn't do with your suggestions or at least not that I can see :)).

Comment: @Leena No, you won't need multiple dictionaries. Have a closer look and see that the `Product` class stores all the information.  Just like `tell_price` returns `self.products[name].price`, a `tell_quantity` method could `return self.products[name].quantity`. Your question was not about creating objects based on user input, it was about retrieving information.

Comment: Is there any way I could create new class object through user input though?  So how do I do that? EDIT: not the original question, I am simply wondering how you'd do that, since the rest of my code wouldn't fit what you suggested :)

Comment: @Leena Of course.  `Product(input('Product Name'), float(input('Product Price)), int(input('Product Quantity')))`

Comment: I mean, where should I put that?  I tried similar (not identical) things, and they didn't seem to work properly to create an object, bc they seemingly just created useless strings. This is something I have never found anywhere tbh. So, to answer your question, what is stopping me is that I have just now begun, I still don't know many things, and I was waiting for an answer that could help me understand it better.

Comment: @Leena perhaps you should open a new question

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't make your tellprice include user input.

```
def tellprice(self): #method should return price of object
    return self.price
```

Then in main (this is significantly simplified):

```
inp = input("Di quale prodotto vuoi conoscere il prezzo? ")
print(inp.tellprice)
```

Obviously this assumes they put in the correct product name, so some way of indicating to the user that they're incorrect might be useful